# How to plot this type of correlation matrix in Python?

Tags: machine-learning, seaborn, data-science, data-visualization, data-analysis

[How to plot this type of correlation matrix in Python???](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYt48.png)

Comment: You don't mention where the image comes from. It might be from [this Towards Data Science article](https://towardsdatascience.com/better-heatmaps-and-correlation-matrix-plots-in-python-41445d0f2bec). Please read that article carefully, especially the first sentence that tells that you can use the [heatmapz package](https://pypi.org/project/heatmapz/).

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns; sns.set_theme()
uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data)
```

[image]